# Unexpected async behavior: Springs's @Async vs RxJava

Tags: multithreading, spring-mvc, asynchronous, rx-java

I' playing around with Spring, RxJava and non blocking data processing. In my test applications I want to implement the following test work flow:

1. [RT] Receive request
2. [RT] Start processing asynchronously in a worker thread
3. [WT] Do some (expensive) initialization work
4. [WT] Call a remote system asynchronously to get a value
5. [HT] Execute the request to the remote system
6. [HT] Forward the result of the response to a worker thread
7. [WT] Do more (expensive) work with the result from the remote system
8. [WT] Return the final result

RT : Request Thread (Tomcat NIO)

WT : Worker Thread (Threadpool with fixed size of 1 and a queue size of 5)

HT : Hystrix Thread (Hystrix threadpool with default setting)

*(This is just an example to simulate expensive data processing in combination with the dependency to a remote resource)*

I have two variants of the code:

1. Using `@Async` to call the WT (Step 2) and Rx’s `Observable`'s for the rest (`http://localhost:9001/value`)
2. Only using Rx’s Observables (`http://localhost:9001/value-rx`)

(`http://localhost:9002/value` is the remote resource)

Variant 2 is working pretty fine, but variant 1 (with `@Async`) runs into some problems. By analyzing the exceptions, thread dumps, thread pool states and log files, it looks like the `ListenableFuture` (returned by the `@Async` service method in step 2) is blocking the thread pool infinitely, the thread itself is WAITING. So RxJava is unable to run the code of the callbacks as desired in the given thread pool (step 6). after 30 second an exception is thrown and the entire process fails, because the thread pool is still blocked, I don’t understand why.

If I use variant 1 multiple times, the second (and all following requests), are failing in step 2 (instead of 6), because the thread pool (size = 1) is still blocked with the `ListenableFuture` (stack trace below).

Variant 2 is able handle multiple request “at the same time” without problems until the queue is full, even with just 1 request thread and 1 worker thread.

- In both cases I'm using a modified version of [this](https://github.com/lukas-krecan/future-converter/blob/master/spring-rxjava/src/main/java/net/javacrumbs/futureconverter/springrx/ObservableListenableFuture.java) to map an instance of `Observable` to `ListenableFuture`.
- I have added additional logging to the controller and service classes. This makes it easier to see in which thread the code parts are executed.

**Why `@Async` is causing this and how can I fix that?**

Here is the code:

*App1Controller*

```
@Slf4j
@RestController
public class App1Controller {

    @Autowired
    private App1Service app1Service;

    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping("/value")
    public ListenableFuture<String> value() {
        final ListenableFuture<String> future;
        log.info("before invoke 'app1Service'");
        future = this.app1Service.value();
        log.info("after invoke 'app1Service'");
        return future;
    }

    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping("/value-rx")
    public ListenableFuture<String> valueRx() {
        final Observable<String> observable;

        log.info("before invoke 'app1Service'");
        observable = this.app1Service.valueRx();
        log.info("after invoke 'app1Service'");

        return new ObservableListenableFuture<>(observable);
    }
}
```

*App1Service*

```
@Slf4j
@Service
public class App1Service {

    @Autowired
    private TaskExecutor taskExecutor;

    @Autowired
    private App2Service app2Service;

    @Async
    public ListenableFuture<String> value() {
        final ListenableFuture<String> future;

        log.info("before start processing");
        this.doSomeStuff();
        future = new ObservableListenableFuture<>(this.valueFromApp2Service());
        log.info("after start processing");

        return future;
    }

    public Observable<String> valueRx() {
        final Observable<String> observable;

        log.info("before start processing");

        observable = Observable.<String>create(s -> {
            this.doSomeStuff();
            this.valueFromApp2Service().subscribe(
                    result -> {
                        log.info("next (processing)");
                        s.onNext(result);
                    },
                    throwable -> {
                        log.info("error (processing)");
                        s.onError(throwable);
                    },
                    () -> {
                        log.info("completed (processing)");
                        s.onCompleted();
                    });
        }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.from(this.taskExecutor));

        log.info("after start processing");

        return observable;
    }

    private Observable<String> valueFromApp2Service() {
        final AsyncSubject<String> asyncSubject;

        log.info("before invoke 'app2Service'");

        asyncSubject = AsyncSubject.create();
        this.app2Service.value().observeOn(Schedulers.from(this.taskExecutor)).subscribe(
                result -> {
                    log.info("next (from 'app2Service')");
                    asyncSubject.onNext(this.doSomeMoreStuff(result));
                }, throwable -> {
                    log.info("error (from 'app2Service')");
                    asyncSubject.onError(throwable);
                }, () -> {
                    log.info("completed (from 'app2Service')");
                    asyncSubject.onCompleted();
                });

        log.info("after invoke 'app2Service'");

        return asyncSubject;
    }

    private void doSomeStuff() {
        log.info("do some expensive stuff");
        this.sleep(1000);
        log.info("finish some expensive stuff");
    }

    private String doSomeMoreStuff(final String valueFromRemote) {
        log.info("do some more expensive stuff with '{}'", valueFromRemote);
        this.sleep(2000);
        log.info("finish some more expensive stuff with '{}'", valueFromRemote);
        return "MODIFIED " + valueFromRemote;
    }

    private void sleep(final long milliSeconds) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(milliSeconds);
        } catch (final InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

*App2Service*

```
@Slf4j
@Service
public class App2Service {

    @HystrixCommand(commandKey = "app2")
    public Observable<String> value() {
        Observable<String> observable;

        log.info("before invoke remote service");

        observable = new ObservableResult<String>() {

            @Override
            public String invoke() {
                log.info("invoke");
                return new RestTemplate().getForEntity("http://localhost:9002/value", String.class).getBody();
            }

        };

        log.info("after invoke remote service");

        return observable;
    }
}
```

*Configuration*

Application (main/configuration class):

```
@EnableCircuitBreaker
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableAsync
    public static class AsyncConfiguration {

        @Bean
        public TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
            final ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor;

            taskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
            taskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(1);
            taskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(1);
            taskExecutor.setQueueCapacity(5);
            taskExecutor.setThreadNamePrefix("worker-");

            return taskExecutor;
        }
    }
}
```

application.properties:

```
server.port=9001
server.tomcat.max-threads=1
hystrix.command.app2.fallback.enabled=false
hystrix.command.app2.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds=15000
```

*Log output of variant 1 (first call)*

```
16:06:31.871 [nio-9001-exec-1] before invoke 'app1Service'
16:06:31.879 [nio-9001-exec-1] after invoke 'app1Service'
16:06:31.887 [       worker-1] before start processing
16:06:31.888 [       worker-1] do some expensive stuff
16:06:32.890 [       worker-1] finish some expensive stuff
16:06:32.891 [       worker-1] before invoke 'app2Service'
16:06:33.135 [x-App2Service-1] before invoke remote service
16:06:33.136 [x-App2Service-1] after invoke remote service
16:06:33.137 [x-App2Service-1] invoke
16:06:33.167 [       worker-1] after invoke 'app2Service'
16:06:33.172 [       worker-1] after start processing
16:07:02.816 [nio-9001-exec-1] Exception Processing ErrorPage[errorCode=0, location=/error]

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot forward after response has been committed
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:328)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:439)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.throwable(StandardHostValve.java:399)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.AsyncContextImpl.setErrorState(AsyncContextImpl.java:438)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.asyncDispatch(CoyoteAdapter.java:291)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.asyncDispatch(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1709)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:649)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1521)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1478)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

*Log output of variant 2 (first call)*

```
16:07:54.465 [nio-9001-exec-1] before invoke 'app1Service'
16:07:54.472 [nio-9001-exec-1] before start processing
16:07:54.500 [nio-9001-exec-1] after start processing
16:07:54.500 [nio-9001-exec-1] after invoke 'app1Service'
16:07:54.517 [       worker-1] do some expensive stuff
16:07:55.522 [       worker-1] finish some expensive stuff
16:07:55.522 [       worker-1] before invoke 'app2Service'
16:07:55.684 [x-App2Service-1] before invoke remote service
16:07:55.685 [x-App2Service-1] after invoke remote service
16:07:55.686 [x-App2Service-1] invoke
16:07:55.717 [       worker-1] after invoke 'app2Service'
16:08:05.786 [       worker-1] next (from 'app2Service')
16:08:05.786 [       worker-1] do some more expensive stuff with 'value from app2 service'
16:08:07.791 [       worker-1] finish some more expensive stuff with 'value from app2 service'
16:08:07.791 [       worker-1] completed (from 'app2Service')
16:08:07.791 [       worker-1] next (processing)
16:08:07.792 [       worker-1] completed (processing)
```

*Thread dump for WT (after using variant 1)*

```
"worker-1" #24 prio=5 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007fe2be8cf000 nid=0x5e03 waiting on condition [0x0000000123413000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000006c0d68fb0> (a org.springframework.util.concurrent.ListenableFutureTask)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.awaitDone(FutureTask.java:429)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
    at org.springframework.util.concurrent.SettableListenableFuture.get(SettableListenableFuture.java:122)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionInterceptor$1.call(AsyncExecutionInterceptor.java:110)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - <0x00000006c0d68170> (a java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker)
```

*Thread dump for WT (after using variant 2)*

```
"worker-1" #24 prio=5 os_prio=31 tid=0x00007fc6136dd800 nid=0x5207 waiting on condition [0x000000012d638000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000006c02f5388> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1067)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1127)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None
```

**SOLUTION**

The async intercepter uses a simple `Future` and can't handle a `ListenableFuture`. After I have reviewed the thread dumps again, I noticed the `FutureTask.get` get. This is a blocking call. That means variant 1 is a builtin deadlock when using with just 1 thread.

This code works:

Controller

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping("/value")
public ListenableFuture<String> value() {
    final SettableListenableFuture<String> future;
    this.app1Service.value(future);
    return future;
}
```

Service

```
@Async
public void value(final SettableListenableFuture<String> future) {
    this.doSomeStuff();
    this.valueFromApp2Service().subscribe(future::set, future::setException);
}
```

Comment: It would be nice to add imports to the code sample....

Answer (score 0):

I think you have already answered your question (or I'm missing something):

> If I use variant 1 multiple times, the second (and all following
>   requests), are failing in step 2 (instead of 6), because the thread
>   pool (size = 1) is still blocked with the ListenableFuture (stack
>   trace below).

Your `TaskExecutor` has only 1 thread available, that is being used for the `@Async`. Then, from that thread, you want to use your `TaskExecutor` again for the Observable:

```
    this.app2Service.value().observeOn(Schedulers.from(this.taskExecutor)).subscribe(
```

but, there are no more threads available on your pool. If you **increase the coreSize, or define a different TaskExecutor for the RxJava stuff**, it should work.

**EDIT**

If you *really* need to execute `app1Service.value()` asynchronously, you can remove the @Asynch from it, and submit the task explicitly to the taskExecutor, so that you can add a callback to the `ListenableFuture`. If you change the result type to a `DeferredResult`, you can set the result of it when the callback of the `ListenableFuture` gets executed:

```
@Autowired
private TaskExecutor taskExecutor;

@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping("/value")
public DeferredResult<String> value() {

    final DeferredResult<String> dr = new DeferredResult<String>();
    taskExecutor.execute(() -> {
        final ListenableFuture<String> future = app1Service.value();
        future.addCallback(new ListenableFutureCallback<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(String result) {
                dr.setResult(result);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable ex) {
                dr.setErrorResult(ex);
            }
        });
    });
    return dr;
}
```

Or, of course, use your solution, that is nicer.

Comment: I also described that variant 2 is working under the same conditions and also can handle more requests at the same time. The simple solution is: I can't use a ListenableFuture as return type of a @Async method. Spring is just using the Future functionality and calls the blocking 'get' method.

Comment: Right. Spring is calling `future.get()` in the `AsyncExecutionInterceptor`, because it's the only thing it can do, it simply has no other way to get the result of the computation of  `app1Service.value()` to dispatch the request. Actually, I think you do not need `@Async` at all, as you are already using RxJava.